# In atmega128 bootloader.hex file missing

Tags: arduino

I want to use atmega128. I have added atmega128 with the help of [Megacore](https://github.com/MCUdude/MegaCore) .
But bootloader.hex file is not generating when I compile the file.
Now, what can I do to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the Arduino ecosystem and not about IoT.  Even if your end goal is IoT related, you first need to overcome this Arduino-specific problem with Arduino-specific resources.  If that then enables you to approach an IoT goal, at that point the IoT goal might make an appropriate question.  But this does not.

Comment: `"bootloader.hex file is not generating when I compile the file"` - does it also link? No error messages at all? Are you looking in the correct place? Maybe it is in another directory.